# What is wrong with this batch-script? I only get an endless list

Tags: batch-file

Following situation:
I have a folder with 140 Protocol-files with the following format (I censored some of this)

```
    LÖSCHPROTOKOLL

HDShredder 3.2
licenses for
%Corporation%
%address%
%address%

Drive: %numbers and letters%
Controller: IDE #0
Kanal: Primary 
Gerät: Master   
LUN: N/A
serial number: %numbers and letters% 
Größe: 78165360 Sektoren (38166 MB)   

HDShredder gestartet am 2.01.2012 um 14:48:46
Verwendete Löschmethode: %deletion methode% (Standard)

Durchlauf 1 von 3 gestartet um 14:48:46
Lösche
Muster: FFFFFFFF
Durchlauf 2 von 3 gestartet um 15:02:34
Lösche
Muster: 00000000
Durchlauf 3 von 3 gestartet um 15:16:23
Lösche
Muster: 55555555
Beendet am 2.01.2012 um 15:30:12

END OF FILE
```

However the files are named like `SHRED001.LOG` `SHRED002.LOG` etc and I like to rename them with there serial number.

This is what I tried so far

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo test


for %%d in (C:\Protokolle\protokolle\SHRED*) do (
    for /F "skip=13 eol=; delims=?" %%i in (%%d) do (
      echo %%i >> C:\Protokolle\protokolle\liste.txt    
      echo %%i
    )
)
```

When it's finished it should rename the files (not implemented yet) as mentioned above and collect all numbers in an extern file `liste.txt`

But when I start the batch all I get is an endless file of text starting with one serial number and the content of all text files combined.

Hope somebody has an idea.
Greetings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the finished working script, thanks for your help :)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A files=0
SET /A todo=0

::  Checking wheather a log-file exists
::  If not: Error message and exit.
IF NOT EXIST .\SHRED* (
    ECHO No matching logfile found.
    ECHO Exit!
    ECHO.
    PAUSE
    EXIT
)

::for the "loading Screen"
@FOR %%e in (".\SHRED*") do set /A files=files+1
ECHO !files! Files found!
:: waiting... this way we avoid the need of pressing a button
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > NUL

FOR %%d IN (".\SHRED*") do (
    ::  Checking for a "Seriennummer"-String and copying everything after it
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i IN ('FINDSTR /c:"serial number" "%%d"') DO (
        CLS
        ::    for the "loading Screen"
        SET  /A todo=todo+1
        ::   copy string for string manipulation
        SET  tmp=%%i
        ::   get rid of leading space
        SET  serial=!tmp: =!
        ::   delete the last character of the string
        SET  serial=!serial:~0,-1!
        ::   ECHOing of the serial and the "loading screen"
        ECHO !serial! !todo! von !files!
        ::   log serial to list file
        ECHO !serial!>> ".\1Uebersicht.txt"
        ::   rename file
        MOVE "%%d" ".\!serial!.log"
    )
)

::  checking if there is still a log-file left
IF EXIST ".\SHRED*" (
    ECHO An error occoured.
    ECHO Not all log-files were renamed
    ECHO.
    PAUSE
    EXIT
)

CLS
ECHO !files! files renamed.
ECHO overview list created.
ECHO please refresh the directory
ECHO.
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Your inner for-loop `for /F "skip=13 eol=; delims=?" %%i in (%%d) do (` will iterate over *all lines* in the file given as `%%d`, omitting the first 13 lines ([reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true)). That's why the output looks like you describe it. If I understand correctly, you only want to parse out the lines starting with the string `serial number:` - you can achieve this by using `FINDSTR` ([reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true)). I tried to write up the script including renaming you:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%d IN ("C:\Protokolle\protokolle\SHRED*") do (
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i IN ('FINDSTR /c:"serial number" "%%d"') DO (
       ECHO %%i
       :: copy string for string manipulation
       SET tmp=%%i
       :: get rid of leading space
       SET serial=!tmp: =!
       :: log serial to list file
       ECHO !serial! >> "C:\Protokolle\protokolle\liste.txt"
       :: rename file
       MOVE "%%d" "C:\Protokolle\protokolle\SHRED!serial!.log"
    )
)
```

Comment: WOW! the ECHOing and writing into the TXT works well!!
But I get an syntax error at the renaming part...?

Comment: Uh, yea, sorry - `REN` does not accept a full path as destination. You would need to use `MOVE` for cross-directory renaming - correcting...

Comment: this also does not work (syntax error)... however, if i don't use `.log` after `!serial!` it renames the files ... but not as "txt" or "log" files but as "data" files with no extension

Comment: Hm, I explicitly tried it on my end and it worked. Just did so again, to be sure. Do any of the pathes and files contain spaces? That will cause trouble and quotes need to be around all the places where they come up (literals as well as variables).

Comment: no, all the pathes are exactly the same.
the only thing i changed is `('FINDSTR /c:"Seriennummer" %%d')` "serial number" to "Seriennummer" which is german. could this cause any Problems?

Comment: No, that shouldn't cause any problems at all. I cannot get to reproduce the error. What format is the "Seriennummer" in, ? Is it one like outputted by a `DIR`, e.g. something like `C812-38BC`? That format would be OK, but if the "Seriennummer" contains spaces or other characters that are special to the Win32 shell, it might very well cause the problem.

Comment: I've added quotes everywhere where pathes/files with special characters could become problematic - maybe this will already help you out? I'm really at a loss here... Btw, what does it say - still a syntax error?

Comment: mhh the most exotic character is a "-" no spaces or something like this.
there ist a new error with your modified script.

`the syntax for tha data name, directoryname or the drivename is wrong`i hope I translated that correctly.

Comment: This is really a tough one! Because I couldn't find a sample log file via Google, I even downloaded HDShredder (free) and tried wiping a dummy disk in a VM, just to find that the free version does not allow to write logfiles :( Now this new error message in the quote-version is sort of telling, at least, see e.g. [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc956689). `MOVE` now accepts the parameters but there **is** some special character sneaking in somewhere, but without the exact input, I just can't tell...

Comment: I thank you so much for your effort and help! I would upvote you 1000 times if I could!
I'm now on vacation, on monday I will take a closer look and see wheather i can find the special character :)
you are a great person

Comment: I finaly found the solution, there always was an obscure character after every serial in the txt, which I ignored.
So i deleted every last character and now it works fine, thanks for your support